# How to iterate Json object and pass the Add, intA, intB values from below json to list using Angular 4

Tags: angular

How to iterate the below json in .ts and get the int fields and operation like Add etc.. in a list using angular 2

`let json = { "Header": null, "Body": { "Add": { "intA": "2","intB": "3" }}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Two points:
1. Remove extra brace from your json (hope you just typed it).
2. You can use json.Body. Add if you getting it as object. Else if you are getting JSON in string format then you need to parse it first.

```
let json = JSON.parse(json_in_string_format)
json.Body.Add
```

Hope it resolves your question